# How to handle SSL in API automation testing through Java code and TestNg test classes?

Tags: ssl-certificate, web-api-testing

I created a truststore through java and wrote a script to access the desired URL. It's perfectly working.
But when I call the certificate class in my TestNG class where I do PUT/POST request, I get Response as 200 along with the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null  at
>   org.apache.http.util.Asserts.notNull(Asserts.java:52)     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.determineRoute(ProxySelectorRoutePlanner.java:133)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the following code snippet:

First, create a cert in Java KeyStore.

```java
@BeforeTest
public void cert() {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "KeyStore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "Password");

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
            }
        };

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```